# Can't login (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

So I need to make a whole login system for my graduation project. I already made a database on mysql which works perfectly. The register part of the login works but if I try to login with the account I just made, it doesnt work. Most of the time I'm getting the error 'Password/e-mail is wrong' while its correct?

Thanks in advance!

```
   <?php
    include("config.php");
    session_start();

    $email =$_POST['email'];
   $password =$_POST['password'];
   if(empty($email))
    {

        exit();

    }else {
      $stmt =mysqli_stmt_init($db);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?;";

      if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
      {

        echo"No data";
      }else
      {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
             $combicheck = password_verify($password,$row['password']);
            if($combicheck == false)
            {

                echo"Password / email is wrong";
                  exit();
            }else if($combicheck == true){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
            header('Location: index.html');
            echo"Logged in";
            }

        }else
        {
          echo"Failed";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you insert as passwords? What is `var_dump($password, $row['password']);`?

Comment: `var_dump(mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);)` would be helpful to know too

Comment: So if you make an account you need to type in an email and password. This will be inserted in the database automaticly.  'password' and 'email' are the names of the textboxes on the register-page which I convert into '$password' and '$email' so i can use them to compare with the data in the database.

Comment: Is the password column in the database at least 60 characters wide?

Comment: I dont know if I need to declare "password_verify"? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: You didn't answer our questions - what is the dump of those variables?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very experienced..What do you mean with that?

Comment: Put `var_dump($password, $row['password']);` after your `if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {`

Comment: Alright, Im going to test that tommorow. Thanks in advance-!

Comment: You also output content after your redirect which isn't going to work

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: What value did yoy store in your password column in database?? It should be the string you get from **password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="" /> <br />
  <input type="password" name="" /> <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

Change display_errors=Off to display_errors=On  in your php.ini file

if method="POST" 
then $_POST in php

if method="GET"
then $_GET in php

If you are not sure is GET or POST method

debug using

In your login.php

```
echo "This is Post method";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "This is Get method";
var_dump($_GET);
```